Erron on Starting Keycloak - default setup
Hello I am trying to set up keycloak on my laptop. I have windows 11 OS
The steps I take are following:

Download latest version of keycloak  (currently: keycloak-24.0.4) from https://www.keycloak.org/downloads

unzip the file in (C:\keycloak) and run the follwing command in dos : C:\keycloak\bin\kc.bat start-dev --http-port 8180 --log=file --log-file=C:\keycloak\logs\root-log.log


Result: Keycloak fails to start
keycloak log:
2024-05-29 13:22:45,533 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.sql.SQLException: Acquisition timeout while waiting for new connection
....
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Please add more information to your question. What version of Keycloak are you trying to start?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Added details, I am simple trying to setup / start keycloak  enable testing with oauth in my application

only running the keycloak it won't works, did you start an SQL server and set up the configuration for the keycloak instance?
check https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config#category-database for JVM args org ENV variables to set a SQL server.

The default installation should work as is. Infact it worked after I renamed my directory in which keycloak was installed

The default installation should work as is. Infact it worked after I renamed my directory in which keycloak was installed
